# Grape token auth "error": "404 API Version Not Found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, grape-api

I am using rails application, setup grape, and trying to authenticate all the endpoints. So tried grape token auth https://github.com/mcordell/grape_token_auth and setup as told in the github doc. These are my configurations.

initializers/gta.rb

```
GrapeTokenAuth.setup! do |config|
  config.mappings = { user: User }
  config.secret   = 'aaa'
end
```

For api this is the folder structure

```
app/api/tmo/api.rb -> mounted two version root file
app/api/tmo/vl/root.rb -> mounted all the other files for v1
app/api/tmo/vl/restaurants.rb -> here lies the mount authentication

include GrapeTokenAuth::MountHelpers
include GrapeTokenAuth::TokenAuthentication
mount_registration(to: '/auth', for: :user)
mount_sessions(to: '/auth', for: :user)
mount_token_validation(to: '/auth', for: :user)
mount_confirmation(to: '/auth', for: :user)
```

So my routes are like

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 9309
POST       /auth/api/v1(/.:format)
DELETE     /auth/api/v1(/.:format)
PUT        /auth/api/v1(/.:format)
POST       /auth/api/v1/sign_in(.:format)
DELETE     /auth/api/v1/sign_out(.:format)
GET        /auth/api/v1/validate_token(.:format)
GET        /auth/confirmation/api/v1(/.:format)
GET        /api/v1/statuses/public_timeline(.:format)
```

When i access /api/v1/statuses/public_timeline it says 401 unauthorized, so authenticate_user! method is working

But when i post to /auth/api/v1 i get the following error

```
{  
  "error": "404 API Version Not Found"
}
```

How do i check where the error is happening or how do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem while trying to setup `grape_token_auth`. I resolved it by doing the following:

```
namespace :auth do
  mount_registration(to: '/', for: :user)
  mount_sessions(to: '/', for: :user)
  mount_token_validation(to: '/', for: :user)
  mount_confirmation(to: '/ ', for: :user)
end
```

In this case, you can call `v1/auth/sign_out` for instance, and should work. Without the namespace, you would call the endpoints this way directly: `v1/sign_out`.

Not sure if intentional or if there was a change in the Grape API, but using the default config of `to: '/auth'` will change the root for the auth endpoints to `/auth`, meaning you will have to call endpoints like `/auth/v1/sign_out`and provide the `version` to Grape by other means so it does not complain about it.

Originally posted in https://github.com/mcordell/grape_token_auth/issues/52#issuecomment-277449284